# bags and wheelchair

Tags: luggage, layovers, jfk

Me and my husband are going from JFK to Hanover on the 23rd of May 2019.
Layover will be in Manchester for 8 hours. We have two bags up to 50lb.

My questions are:

1. Do we need to pay for our bags?
2. For this 8 hours do we need to pick up our bags in Manchester?
3. Do I need to order a wheelchair?

Comment: This is quite broad. 1. Depends on the airline 2. Depends on the airline and your itenerary 3. Why would you need a wheelchair? Are you or your husband disabled, or does one of you just get tired easily? If you can [edit] some details in we should be able to help you

Comment: These are all questions best answered by the airline itself. Have you tried contacting them, or at least checking their website?

Comment: I assume you mean Hannover, Germany. 1/2 depends a lot on you tickets so no answer can be given. If you need assistance at Manchester, looks like they're large enough to accommodate that (I'd contact the inbound airline . lookup the Manchester airport website for that). But an 8hr lay-over... that's a long wait, There should have been better options.

Answer (score 2):

The only non-stops on JFK-MAN and MAN-HAJ are Thomas Cook Airlines and Flybe, respectively.

I'm pretty sure this means you have bough the two tickets separately.

Of course, we'll consider you have taken into account the fact that the JFK-MAN flight is overnight, so if you leave from JFK on the 23rd, you'll be in MAN on the 24th, and your second flight should leave on that date.

On Thomas Cook Airlines, your hold luggage allowance depends on the fare:

- If you booked an "economy light" fare, no hold luggage is included.
- Otherwise, flights from the USA include one hold bag weighing 23 kg (50 pounds) max per passenger.

On Flybe, likewise, there are fares with or without hold luggage:

- A "Just fly" fare will not include any hold luggage
- Other fares will include one hold bag weighing 23 kg (50 pounds) max per passenger.

In both cases, if you bought a ticket without hold luggage included, you will have to pay extra to add luggage to your booking. It is usually cheaper to do it online in advance rather than at the airport.

As your two tickets are separate, this is what you will have to do in Manchester:

- deplane
- go through immigration (passport control)
- reclaim your bags
- go through customs
- go to the departures area
- find the check-in desk for your second flight
- Check-in before the deadline for that flight.
- Go through security
- Go to your gate
- Board before the boarding deadline

It is quite possible that the check-in desk for the second flight will actually not be open. In most cases you can only drop your bags 2 hours before the flight at the earliest, so you'll be stuck with your luggage for about 5 hours.

If you need a wheelchair, you should contact each of the airlines, they will arrange that for you.